# Delete an object from Arraylist

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, iterator, actionlistener

I have an ArrayList of Objects (Name, a few numbers, etc) that I can open and see on a JTable (name, etc). I can add an object to the jtable and add it to the arraylist. Whe I try to remove an object from the JTable, it wont delete also on my ArrayList. I made this ActionListener and I tried both methods for removing the Object (with remove() and with a iterator)

```
    class ButtonRemovePersoAL implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int numerorows = table.getSelectedRows().length;
            for(int i=0; i < numerorows ; i++ ) {
                String Name = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0); // I search for the first case of the JTable to catch the Object to erase
                for(Object object : myarraylistofobjects) {
                    if(Name.equals(object.getName())) {
                        myarraylistofobjects.remove(object);
                    }
                 }                  
                                  // OR
                Iterator<Object> itr = myarraylistofobjects().iterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Object object = itr.next();
                       if (Name.equals(object.getName())) {
                       itr.remove();
                    }

                }

                tablemodel.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow()); // I delete finally my row from the jtable
            }
        }

    }
```

What am I missing ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please follow Java capitalization conventions. Also, what is the value of `Name`, and are you sure your if condition evaluates to `true`? Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Is it possible to use `Vector` instead of `ArrayList`?  `DefaultTableModel` has a [constructor for `Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29) and it will make everything else so much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start here...

```
int numerorows = table.getSelectedRows().length;
for(int i=0; i < numerorows ; i++ ) {
    String Name = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0); // I search for the first case of the JTable to catch the Object to erase
```

Basically, you get the number of selected rows, but you only ever use the index of the first selected row...`table.getSelectedRow()`

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow%28%29)...

> **Returns:**
> the index of the first selected row

What you should do is

```
for(int i : table.getSelectedRows()) {
```

Which will loop through each selected index.

You should avoid doing this...

```
String Name = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
```

As the view may be sorted, meaning that the view index (selected row) won't map directly to the model row, instead, you should use

```
String name = (String) table.getValueAt(i, 0);
```

From here, it all get's a little messy...

When you do something like...

```
tablemodel.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
```

All the indices are no longer valid (not to mention you shouldn't be using `table.getSelectedRow()`)

Instead, when you remove the item from your `ArrayList`, you should be making note of it and then walking the `TableModel` removing any item that is in the remove list...

For example...

```
List<String> removedNames = new ArrayList<String>(25);
for(int i : table.getSelectedRows() ) {
    String name = (String) table.getValueAt(i, 0);
    removedNames.add(name);
    //...
}

int index = 0;
while (index < tableModel.getRowCount()) {
    Object value = tableModel.valueAt(index, 0);
    if (value != null && removedNames.contains(value.toString()) {
        tableModel.removeRow(index);
    } else {
        index++;
    }
}
```

To by quite frank.  I simpler solution would be to create a custom `TableModel`, extending from `AbstractTableModel` which wrapped around your `ArrayList`...

Answer (score 0):

if you want only to delete one row just

```
  myarraylistofobjects.remove(selectedRow) ;

  tablemodel.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
```

These two lines will solve your problem